# direct initialization of a POD variable does not work but copy initialization does when pushing the variable onto a vector

Tags: c++, initialization, copy-initialization

Why does the following code fail to compile, while the two examples after compile successfully? I'm using VS 2008 on Windows 7.

---

Direct initialization of POD (fails):

```
int pod();
std::vector<int> pods;
//pods.push_back(pod); // This will generate a compiler error
// Compile error: 1>c:\test.hpp(43) : error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'const int &'
```

---

Copy initialization of POD (succeeds:

```
int pod = int();
std::vector<int> pods;
pods.push_back(pod); // No error!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look up "[most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)" (it has been discussed over and over again here, too).

```
int pod(); // this does not declare (nor define) an integer
```

By the way, why did you put that `1` in the MyClass example?

Comment: I removed the '1'. It was a typo.

Comment: @ChrisMorris, I think you will find the third example "non-working" now, too.